# how to add gmail widget in galaxy ace duos

Tags: gmail, samsung-galaxy-ace, app-widgets, 2.3.3-gingerbread

> How can i add gmail widget in my background screen. am unable to get
>   it from widgets. FYI i can see Samsung Default Email widget

Comment: Why downvote for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Gingerbread has a built in gmail widget but take a look on the Google Play store. I found an example: "[Gmail Inbox Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deselaers.gmailinboxwidget&hl=en)" that is compatible with gingerbread and there may be others. You could set up gmail in the default mail app and use it's widget but that sounds like a horrible work around to me.

[Aqua Mail - email app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kman.AquaMail) Says it's compatible with 2.1 and up. I think this would be the same as using the default mail client on your phone (setting up gmail in the app and using it as an email client) but it does have an email widget.

[Email Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.foobarsoft.emailwidget) Looks like it will do what you want but it's not free. Check to make sure it is compatible with your version of gmail before buying.